# How could I use curl PHP in the dedicated server using Plesk panel

Tags: php, laravel, curl, libcurl

I have an applicatoin using `CURL` PHP to fetch data from remote server using Laravel Framework, so localy it's working fin and also in the shardhost it's working perfectly. It's give me a bug when runing the schedule and the log file look like:

```
[2020-09-01 22:50:23] local.INFO: Res Name: [test] 10fb66f8
[2020-09-01 22:50:23] local.INFO:   
[2020-09-01 22:50:24] local.ERROR: result:{"error":"invalid_client"}  
[2020-09-01 22:33:51] local.ERROR: Undefined index: access_token {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Undefined index: access_token at /var/www/vhosts/Applicatio/app/Services/PosApi.php:163)
```

and the curl code is :

```
 private function OAuthLogin()
    {
        $fields = array(
            'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
            'client_id' => env('POS_CLIENT'),
            'client_secret' => env('POS_SECRET'),
            'scope' => "*",
        );
        $fields_string = "";
        foreach ($fields as $key => $value) {
            $fields_string .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
        }
        $fields_string = rtrim($fields_string, '&');
        $ch = curl_init();
        
        
        curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
            CURLOPT_URL => $this->getTokenLink,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => true,
            CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
            CURLOPT_POST => 1,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'),
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $fields_string,
        ));
    
        $result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
        Log::error("result:" .$result);
        curl_close($ch);
   }
```

so what is wrong with my code?
any suggestion and tips it will be good :).

update:

- when I use `Postman` to test the api also it's working perfectly.

Comment: `when runing the schedule` do you mean this is running as part of a task? like a cronjob? if so, does that environment have the required environment variables like `POS_CLIENT` and `POS_SECRET` ?

Comment: thanks @alanboy to answer, yes I have environment variables

Comment: Have you created the clients on the new vhost? Do the client_id ‘s match?

Comment: I `Log::info($fields)` and found out `client_id` and `client_securet` is not there all of them is `NULL`,
but they still exist on the `.env`, and I don't know why.
so I take the values and put them directly on the array instead of reading them from `.env`. and now it is working fine.